# Decrypt master password of windows API CryptProtectData (presumably)

Tags: encryption, public-key-encryption, password-encryption, encryption-symmetric

Is it possible to decrypt master password if I have data for encryption (text) and the result of encryption of this data (BLOB). 
I want to decrypt Google Chrome master password that is used for encryption data. As I know chrome uses windows API CryptProtectData function. I have plaintext1 and ciphertext1. Also I have ciphertext2 and I want to decrypt plaintext2.

Comment: So you're saying you have a piece of plaintext and the corresponding cyphertext? Obtaining any information about the key from these two items is known as a "known plaintext attack". Any encryption system worth it's salt should be immune to such attacks, so hopefully the answer to your question is no.

Comment: I have the whole of plaintext and the corresponding ciphertext. Maybe it is possible to know the result of salt*master password to decrypt similar plaintext? I have plaintext1 and ciphertext1. Also I have ciphertext2 and I want to decrypt paintext2.

Comment: Fine, I'll give you the link to it - [Known-plaintext attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack) and again, any encryption system worth using these days should be immune to it. Such attacks have been known about for *decades*.

Comment: Thank you for helping to understand!